# Finding same-cost assignments for 3-SAT formulas

Tags: algorithms, 3-sat

Suppose I have a 3-SAT formula in CNF with $ m $ clauses on $ n $ variables,
$$ F = C_1 \wedge \dotsb \wedge C_m, $$
with each clause $ C_i = l_{i_1} \vee l_{i_2} \vee l_{i_3} $ and each literal $ l_k \in \{x_1, \bar{x}_1, \dotsc, x_n, \bar{x}_n\} $.

Define the cost $ E $ of each assignment $ \mathbf{l} = (l_1 \dotsb l_n) $ as the number of clauses not satisfied by it, so that
$$ E(\mathbf{l}) \in \{0, 1, \dotsc, m\} $$
(zero cost corresponding to satisfying assignments).

Finally, suppose the clause density $ m/n $ is sufficiently high so that most (or even all) assignments have nonzero cost (one can show that for large enough $ n, m $, clauses can be deemed independent and the cost distribution becomes a binomial distribution with mean $ m/8 $).

I'm trying to answer the following question: given an assignment $ \mathbf{l} $ with cost $ E(\mathbf{l}) > 0 $, what is the quickest way of finding another assignment $ \mathbf{l}^\prime $ such that $ E(\mathbf{l}^\prime) = E(\mathbf{l}) $?

I haven't been able to find this problem in the literature, and right now I can't do better than random search. Thank you for any insight or even just referrals to some article I might have missed.

Comment: Isn't it **NP**-complete to even determine if there's another satisfying assignment, let alone one of a particular cost?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't expect there to be a polynomial algorithm solving this even for $ E = m/8 $ (the most likely cost for an assignment). But I also expect that an algorithm should exist that performs better than random search --- either in the sense that it's faster on *typical* formulas (like DPLL for the $ E = 0 $ case), or that it is $ O(\omega^n) $ with $ \omega < 2 $ (RandomWalkSAT comes to mind).

Comment: Are you looking for a practical solution or its theoretical complexity?  (If the former look into [MaxSAT solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_satisfiability_problem) and pseudoboolean constraints.  If the latter, it is NP-hard, as David Richerby explains.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry I cannot get your point. Could you please explain more why the determine version is NP-complete?

Comment: @xskxzr Adding a variable $x_0$ into every clause and adding clauses $x_i\vee \bar{x}_0$ (and maybe have to put more effort in converting this CNF into a 3CNF).

Comment: @WillardZhan So which NPC problem is reduced to this problem? Are you describing the reducing process?

Comment: Yes, that's a reduction from 3SAT.

Comment: @WillardZhan Thanks, I seem to got it. It seems you have shown the problem "given a solution of CNF, determine whether there is another solution this CNF" is NPC by reduction from 3SAT. The reduction cannot be directly generalized for proof of 3CNF version of this problem because you cannot simply add $x_0$ into a clause already with 3 literals. I have found [the proof of 3CNF version](https://notendur.hi.is/hh/kennsla/rrr/h06/sudoku.pdf).

Comment: This is related to [Another Solution Problem](https://notendur.hi.is/hh/kennsla/rrr/h06/sudoku.pdf).

Comment: @xskxzr If I knew what the proof was, I would have been sure that my claim was true, so I would have written it as a question.